# Hadoop pipes and new mapred package

Tags: hadoop, pipe, mapreduce

Is there any work going on to port Hadoop pipes from mapred to mapreduce package?

Thanks,
Meg

Answer (score 1):

JIRA issue [MAPREDUCE-1362](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-1362) addresses upgrading pipes to the new mapreduce API, however, it hasn't been updated since January 2010.

In the meantime, I've continued using the old mapred API for developing C++ mappers and reducers.